# Method to query Active Directory works when written as part of a form, but not within it's own class

Tags: c#, winforms, directoryservices

I'm writing an application where, upon receipt of a username, the AD is queried and the information I need is returned. When I write this function just as part of a Windows Forms class, it works perfectly. When I write it as part of a separate class, it fails.

This works

```
public partial class frmBlockCO : Form
{
    public frmBlockCO()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void tbId_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tbName.Text = getADInfo(this.tbId.Text, "displayName");
        this.tbBlock.Text = getADInfo(this.tbId.Text, "department");
    }

    private string getADInfo(string userName, string requestedInfo)
    {
        DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry();
        DirectorySearcher ADSearch = new DirectorySearcher(AD);

        AD.Username = (string)System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        AD.Path = "LDAP://path";

        ADSearch.Filter = String.Format("SAMAccountName={0}", userName);
        ADSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add(requestedInfo);

        SearchResult result = ADSearch.FindOne();
        return (string)result.Properties[requestedInfo][0];
    }
}
```

I put it in it's own class, below, which doesn't work.

```
static class adSearch
{
    public static string getADInfo(string userName, string requestedInfo)
    {
            DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry();
            DirectorySearcher ADSearch = new DirectorySearcher(AD);

            AD.Username = (string)System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            AD.Path = "LDAP://path";

            ADSearch.Filter = String.Format("SAMAccountName={0}", userName);
            ADSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add(requestedInfo);

            SearchResult result = ADSearch.FindOne();
            return (string)result.Properties[requestedInfo][0];
    }
}
```

Now, the weird thing is that when I first took it out of the form and put it into it's own class, it worked fine for a while. It stopped working out of nowhere, and I'm too much of a amateur to figure out why. Now when I run it, I get this:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>   ErrorCode -2147024843
>   HResult -2147024843
>   Message The network path was not found.
>   Source System.DirectoryServices

I can run these two programs side by side, and every time, top version works - bottom version doesn't. Exact same LDAP string, exact same system, exact same inputs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post the client code ("caller") of the "bottom" class?

Comment: this.tbName.Text = adSearch.getADInfo(this.tbId.Text, "displayName");

Comment: Thank you! Let's see the "bottom" class again. What about the `hscAD` identifier (field or local variable or etc)? Why not use this call: `new DirectorySearcher(AD);`?

Comment: The 2 methods are not the same

Comment: That was an editing error on my part while trying to change the specific-to-our-enterprise variable names out with more generic ones. I just missed that one.

Comment: Are you calling the class from the same form? I'm wondering if `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` is returning something different?

Comment: Check id `AD.Username` is being set to the same value for both calls. Also double check if the inputs to both calls are the same i.e. `userName` and `requestedInfo
`

Comment: In the failing case, how are you actually calling the code? Are you calling it from the same form context? Or some other scenario?

Comment: Thank you for all the responses! Mark - I double checked the System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name - it's returning the same value in both (DOMAIN\user). 3dd - I've checked and checked and checked, super meticulously. Peter - I'm calling it from the exact same context. It worked **absolutely fine** for days, I cannot for the life of me figure out why it started throwing that network path not found error message out of nowhere.